# Renderer over Camera View both on same GLSurfaceView?

Tags: android, augmented-reality, glsurfaceview

I am trying to use the same glsurfaceview object to show camera view & render custom openGl drawings over this camera view.

But I found that if I use surface holder without renderer it's ok 
and when I use the renderer without holder it's ok

But when I use both codes for holder & renderer in my activity class I get only the camera view.

I try this code on samsung p1000 galaxy tab, 
but when I try it on htc wild fire an exception thrown "application has stopped unexpectedly..." and even no camera preview is available.

here is the code. if any one can help, it will be appreciated

```
package org.me.glsurfaceview;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Size;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.List;
import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;
import android.opengl.GLU;
import android.util.Log;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.ShortBuffer;
public class ActivityGLSurfaceView extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mGLSurfaceView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mGLSurfaceView.onResume();
    }
    private GLSurfaceView mGLSurfaceView;
    private Camera mCamera;
    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        // ToDo add your GUI initialization code here
        try {
            mGLSurfaceView = new GLSurfaceView(getApplication());
            //mGLSurfaceView.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);

            mGLSurfaceView.setEGLConfigChooser(false);
            mGLSurfaceView.setDebugFlags(2);


            mSurfaceHolder = mGLSurfaceView.getHolder();
            mSurfaceHolder.setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
            mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
            mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);


            mGLSurfaceView.setRenderer(new MyRenderer());
            mGLSurfaceView.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
            setContentView(mGLSurfaceView);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("GlSurfaceView", ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int format, int width, int height) {
        try {
            Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();

            List<Size> sizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
            parameters.setPreviewSize(width, height);
            mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (Exception ex) {

                       Toast.makeText(this, ex.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        try {
            mCamera = Camera.open();
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
                      Toast.makeText(this, ex.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.release();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
                       Toast.makeText(this, ex.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

        public class MyRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

        public MyRenderer() {
            ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(VERTS * 3 * 4);
            vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
            mFVertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();
            ByteBuffer ibb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(VERTS * 2);
            ibb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
            mIndexBuffer = ibb.asShortBuffer();
            float[] coords = {
                -0.5f, -0.5f, 0, // (x1,y1,z1)
                0.5f, -0.5f, 0,
                0.0f, 0.5f, 0
            };
            for (int i = 0; i < VERTS; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {

                    mFVertexBuffer.put(coords[i * 3 + j]);
                }
            }
            short[] myIndecesArray = {0, 1, 2};
            //short[] myIndecesArray = {0, 1};
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

                mIndexBuffer.put(myIndecesArray[i]);
            }
            mFVertexBuffer.position(0);
            mIndexBuffer.position(0);
        }
//Number of points or vertices we want to use
        private final static int VERTS = 3;
//A raw native buffer to hold the point coordinates
        private FloatBuffer mFVertexBuffer;
//A raw native buffer to hold indices
//allowing a reuse of points.
        private ShortBuffer mIndexBuffer;

        public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
            gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);
            gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
            gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
            gl.glLoadIdentity();
            GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 0, 0, -5, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
            gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
            draw(gl);
        }

        public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int w, int h) {
            gl.glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
            float ratio = (float) w / h;
            gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
            gl.glLoadIdentity();
            gl.glFrustumf(-ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 3, 7);
        }

        public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig eglConfig) {
            gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);
            gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_FASTEST);
            //gl.glClearColor(.5f, .5f, .5f, 1);
            gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);
            gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        }

        public void draw(GL10 gl) {
            // gl.glColor4f(1.0f, 0, 0, 0.5f);
            gl.glColor4f(0, 0, 1.0f, 0.5f);
            gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mFVertexBuffer);
            gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, VERTS,
                    GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, mIndexBuffer);

        }
    }
}
```

=======================================================The Manifest===============

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="org.me.glsurfaceview">
         <supports-screens
android:largeScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:smallScreens="true"
android:anyDensity="false"
/>
    <application android:debuggable="true">
         <activity android:name=".ActivityGLSurfaceView" android:label="ActivityGLSurfaceView">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SURFACE_FLINGER
" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
</manifest>
```